# Find and reorder commands using a regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find things like these

```
MakeVariable(magnet, "1", "Enable magnet")
```

and replace with

```
CVariable magnet("magnet", "1", "Enable magnet")
```

Here is what I tried

```
Find What: MakeVariable(([^ ]+),

Replace with: CVariable \1 ("\1 ",
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `MakeVariable\(([^ ]+),`? You could also try `\g<1>` instead of `\1`.

Comment: Actually,  the `(` in the replacement pattern should also be escaped as NPP uses the Boost style conditional replacement patterns where parentheses have special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape literal parentheses in both the search and replacement patterns.

Also, if your first argument is a chunk of word chars use `\w+` to match it:

*Find what*: `MakeVariable\(\s*(\w+)`
*Replace with*: `CVariable $1\("$1"`

*Details*:

- `MakeVariable` - `MakeVariable` text
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 matching one or more word chars

Alternative solution more similar to your original pattern is a `MakeVariable\(\s*(\S+),` regex to search and `CVariable $1\("$1",` pattern to replace (where `\w+` is replaced with `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace symbols).

[image]